# Getting the average of numbers with anticipating wrong user inputs

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {

    float sum, counter = 0, num;
    string d;
    bool t = true;

    while (t) {
        cin >> num;
        sum = sum + num;

        counter += 1;

        while (cin.fail())
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();
            cin >> d;

            if (d == "done") {
                t = false;
                continue;
            } else {
                cout << "Invalid" << endl;
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << sum << ' ' << counter << ' ' << (sum / counter);
    return 0;
}
```

**So I am trying to calculate the average of input numbers with a guess of input as follows:

```
4 5 BadInput 7
-----
Expected output should be:
Enter a number: 4
Enter a number: 5
Enter a number: bad data
Invalid 
Enter a number: 7
Enter a number: done
16 3 5.333333333333333
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: `num` is not initialized. You're reading it with `cin >> num;` but you don't check if it was successful. Therefore `sum = sum + num;` could cause undefined behavior. `sum` is no initialized. Therefore `sum = sum + num;` will always cause undefined behavior.

Comment: I don't understand the line `cin.ignore();` in this context. Could you explain it? You should try to remove it.

Comment: FYI, the `cin.clear()` only clears the *status* bit, like failure.  It does not clear the input buffers.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I think that's exactly what OP wants. The first try is to read the input buffer into a `float`. If it doesn't work the program reads the input buffer into a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to handle bad input, I suggest reading the inputs into a string, and then further process the string. That will make the loop itself much simpler:

```
std::string d;
float sum = 0;
int counter = 0;

while (std::cin >> d) {
    if (d == "done") {
        break;
    }

    try {
        sum += std::stof(d);
        counter++;
    } except (std::logic_error &e) {
        std::cerr << "Invalid input\n";
    }
}

std::cout << sum << ' ' << counter << ' ' << (sum / counter) << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is

```
cin.ignore();
```

The program will read user input and try to interpret it as number. When you enter `"done"` the program can't interpret it and `std::cin.fail()` will return `true`. But `std::cin.ignore()` removes the first character and

```
cin >> d;
```

reads `"one"`. The program won't leave the loop.

Remove

```
cin.ignore();
```

The next problem is the uninitialized variable `sum`. The line

```
sum = sum + num;
```

causes undefined behavior.

The last problem I found is this snippet

```
cin >> num;
sum = sum + num;

counter += 1;
```

The program tries to read the input into the `float` `num`. Then it adds the value of `num` to `sum` and increments the counter even though the read failed. You should first check if the read failed.

This is a possible fix to your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(void) {

    float sum = 0, counter = 0, num = 0;
    std::string d;
    bool t = true;

    while (t) {
        std::cin >> num;
        if (!std::cin.fail()) {
            sum = sum + num;

            counter += 1;
        }

        while (std::cin.fail()) {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin >> d;

            if (d == "done") {
                t = false;
                continue;
            } else {
                std::cout << "Invalid\n";
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << sum << ' ' << counter << ' ' << (sum / counter);
    return 0;
}
```